# pandas -- dropping rows containing nans -- ignore column(s)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to remove from a dataframe (`orig`) rows that correspond with rows in a derivative dataframe (`filtered`) that contain `NaN` values in them. The problem is that the derivative dataframe has a removed column that causes *every* row to be removed. To amend this, I have to reinsert the removed column. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the desired result than reinserting into `filtered` the column removed from it?

```
>>> orig = pd.DataFrame([
                         [1, 1.0, 'one'], 
                         [2, 2.0, 'two'],
                         [100, 100.0, 'one-hundred']
                        ], columns=['Integers', 'Floats', 'Strings'])
>>> numeric = orig.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float'])
>>> numeric
   Integers  Floats
0         1     1.0
1         2     2.0
2       100     100.0
>>> filtered = numeric[np.abs(numeric - numeric.mean())<=(numeric.std())].dropna()
>>> filtered
   Integers  Floats
0       1.0     1.0
1       2.0     2.0
```

The next line will return an empty dataframe because `filtered` does not have the column `Strings` in it and, thus, excludes every row from `orig`.

```
>>> removed_rows = orig[orig.isin(filtered)].dropna()
```

I have to reinsert the non-numeric column removed in the second line before running the line of code above:

```
>>> filtered['Strings'] = orig['Strings']
```

to finally get the desired result:

```
>>> removed_rows
   Integers  Floats Strings
0       1.0     1.0     one
1       2.0     2.0     two
```

If this is the only way to do this, then that's fine -- but I was hoping for a more elegant way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index into `orig`.

```
orig[(np.abs(numeric - numeric.mean()) <= (numeric.std())).all(axis=1)]
```

Or,

```
orig[(np.abs(numeric - numeric.mean()) <= (numeric.std())).min(axis=1)]
```

```
   Integers  Floats Strings
0         1     1.0     one
1         2     2.0     two
```

Comment: Hmm, why `min` ? I am a bit curious, weird way for conver one column df to  `Series`

Comment: @jezrael if even one value in the row is an outlier, the entire row is to be dropped. You find these rows by taking the min of the boolean mask across columns. It's a quick and simple way to index.

Comment: If you'll notice, the mask generated by OP is a two column dataframe.

Comment: Are you sure? `(np.abs(numeric - numeric.mean()) <= (numeric.std()))` return one column `DataFrame`

Comment: Tested in pandas 0.23.0

Comment: @jezrael omg that is so weird... I am using 0.22. Are you using 0.23? But this seems like a numpy problem... so weird

Comment: @coldspeed your solution seems the best -- but I'm a little confused if the use of min() will work in the general sense....does replacing min() with all() produce the same result, because the latter is intuitive to me?

Comment: @aweeeezy No. You can replace `min` with `all(axis=1)` for the same effect.

Comment: @coldspeed, yes that's what I meant -- I edited my comment...this is the solution I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check at all  `True`s per row:

```
orig[(np.abs(numeric - numeric.mean()) <= (numeric.std())).all(axis=1)]
```

In pandas `0.23.0` for some reason `numeric` return only column `float`.

```
print (orig.dtypes)
Integers      int64
Floats      float64
Strings      object
dtype: object

print (orig.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']))
   Floats
0     1.0
1     2.0
2   100.0
```

So better is use `np.number`:

```
print (orig.select_dtypes(include=np.number))
   Integers  Floats
0         1     1.0
1         2     2.0
2       100   100.0
```

Comment: @aweeeezy - So solution create `NaN`s?

Comment: @aweeeezy - Maybe some pandas version problem, check another answers if use pandas below 0.23.0

Comment: I'm using 0.23 -- the issue remains though. Coldspeed's solution works best. Though your last suggestion using any() is close, it must be all() instead to, as Coldspeed said, remove rows if any feature contains an outlier.

Comment: @aweeeezy - Yes, hard check without data, `any` was changed to `all`

Comment: @aweeeezy - Interesting, after investigating problem was found, better is use `np.number` :)